# iframe content not auto submitting

Tags: html, iframe, cross-domain

I have a web page that contains an iframe. In that iframe, the contained page has a form that auto submits back to itself to render a graph. In testing the page I get the following error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://********/" from accessing a cross-origin frame`

I have tried the following:

1. I have set the source of the iframe to be a subdomain of the main site (no luck)
2. Added `sandbox="allow-same-origin"` to the iframe tag some of the content does not load
3. Added `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` header to the web.config of the iframe source

Note both the hosting site and iframe source site both have the same SSL certificate, both are using https

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the two using the same domain?

Comment: the containing page is https://ahdb.org.uk/ and the contents of the iframe is https://porktools.ahdb.org.uk

Comment: I am afraid subdomains are handled like two separate toplevel domains ...

Comment: Thanks @Mazoli, can you post that as an answer? So that I can accept that as an answer to the question.

Comment: sure thx - just did!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid subdomains are handled like two separate toplevel domains.